# angular 2 search input with debounceTime and onFocusOut

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-forms

I have a problem with search input. In Angular 2 project I have search input:

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="data.value" (keyup)="input$.next($event)" (focusout)="onFocusOut($event)" />
```

and on my typescrirpt:

```
input$ = new Subject<any>();
ngOnInit() {
  this.input$
    .do(this.keyUpEventHandler.bind(this))
    .debounceTime(3000)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe((value) => {
      console.log('afterDebounce', value);
// do http request in service
        });
  }

  onFocusOut(event) {
    //this.input$.skipLast(1);
   // do http request in service immediately 
  }
```

And my problem is when I typing... and click enter, simply lost focus from my input component, I call http request but after 3 seconds also call once again. Is any solution to dismiss that last next for input$ observable?

I don't like to unsubscribe whole observable, because I'd like to use it later (if user want to search data) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create two streams of data, One for the 'keyUp' event and one for the 'blur' event. Than with a little bit of RxJs magic do the following :

```
@ViewChild('searchValueInput') searchValueInput: any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.subscribeToInputChanges();
    }

subscribeToInputChanges(){
  let keyUp$:Observable<any>=Observable.fromEvent     
  (this.searchValueInput.nativeElement, 'keyup')
    .debounceTime(3000)
    .distinctUntilChanged();

let focusOut$:Observable<any>=Observable
.fromEvent(this.searchValueInput.nativeElement, 'blur');

  Observable.defer(()=>Observable.race(
    keyUp$,
    focusOut$
  ))
  .take(1)
  .repeat()
  .subscribe(res=>{
    this.http.get('someURL')
    .subscribe(response=>{
      //Handle response
    })
  })
}
```

Any your html:

```
  <input #searchValueInput type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search">
```

The keyUp$ observable is the same as you created.
The focusOut$ observable is very slimier to keyUp$, It been created from 'blur' event and emit data immediately (Without debounceTime).

We combine them together using the [race operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-race) witch tell the observable to use the first observable that emits.

We also wrap this 'race' observable inside another [defer observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer). The defer observable with the [take(1)](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-take) and [repeat()](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-repeat) is responsible for keeping the subscription alive and not always use the same observable (keyUp$ or focusOut$).

Iv'e created a small [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-ekhepb?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html) that show's all of the above in a working example.

Comment: Thank you very much! You made my day :)